# Why invest in managed mutual funds?

Tags: mutual-funds, index-fund, germany

As I can see it, nearly no managed mutual funds beat the index over more than 5/10 years. They don't only have to beat the index, they also must get the  fees back to outperform the index fund. So why would one invest in these management funds, if you will most likely not beat the index? (If you're no Warren Buffett)

Comment: Note that Warren Buffet (BRK) has not beaten the S&P 500 over the past 10 years. He made his killing buying companies that were undervalued in the less transparent markets of the '60s and '70s.

Comment: The simple answer is - you're completely correct.  The "fund" rofl industry is simply a scam writ large.  It's so silly you can't even call it a scam.